# In Asciidoc (and Asciidoctor), how do I format console output best?

Tags: asciidoc

In my `adoc` document, I want to show some output logging to the console.

Should I use `[source]`, `[source,shell]` or nothing before the `----`?

```
----
Solving started: time spent (67), best score (-20init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
    CH step (0), time spent (128), score (-18init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (15), picked move ([Math(101) {null -> Room A}, Math(101) {null -> MONDAY 08:30}]).
    CH step (1), time spent (145), score (-16init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (15), picked move ([Physics(102) {null -> Room A}, Physics(102) {null -> MONDAY 09:30}]).    
----
```

I'd argue it's not really source code (it's output) and I definitely don't output text that happen to contain shell language syntax to be code colored as shell language (because it's not).

Answer (score 3):

The `[source]` and plain `----` notations are identical in this case. I would use either (your preference), without the `shell` type specifier, to get plaintext.